# How Can I reinstall 64 bit ubuntu over 32 bit

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-vista

I installed 32 bit ubuntu on my vista because it ran 32 bit windows however with 3 gigs of ram I think I can push the 64 bit. My pc is freezing a lot which it never did with vista.

How can I wipe and reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: 3G does not imply 64 bit capability.  What hardware do you have?

Comment: amd athalon 64 processor on an acer laptop. I'll admit this is my first shot at Linux so im not 100%

Comment: tell model number of your processor, however i do believe it would be 64 bit compatible

Comment: Acer: kaw 60 is what is says on the bottom of the computer

Comment: @BillTracy is it `KAW 60` or `KAV 60`

Comment: @H.Freeze its 100% KAW

Comment: @BillTracy If i am correct your processor seems to be http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%2064%202650e%20-%20ADG2650IAV4DP%20%28ADG2650DPBOX%29.html, which is indeed 64 bit capable

Comment: I appreciate the help @H.Freeze and i should just pop the 64 bit installer cd in and run it with WINE?

Comment: @BillTracy Also know that you don't exactly need 64 bit system unless you have more than 3.8 gigs of ram.

Comment: @BillTracy don't run it with wine, just `dd` it to a pen drive and try booting from it. `dd if=/path/to/isofile.iso of=/dev/pendrivedevice`

Answer (score 1):

If your machine is truly 64bit compatible (which is an absolute requirement), you will have to reinstall Ubuntu completely if you are wanting the 64-bit version.

You can just re-run the 64bit liveCD and keep the default partitioning settings, or if you wanted more control...

Run the liveCD like you would normally, and select "Something else..." in the partitioning. "Change" the ext4 partition on your computer. Check "format this drive" and set the mount point to "/". You should have a swap already in place, but if you don't, create one with at least 3Gbs in size.

There isn't a *ton* of improvement from 32bit to 64bit, but if your system IS 64bit compatible, you can try it. But again (third time here), you need to make sure your system is 64bit compatible! If it ran 32bit Windows, it sounds like it might be 32bit only!

The "bit" of the computer is based on the hardware, not just the RAM. It's the CPU and motherboard, so look up your specs on google and see if it's really 64 bit.

Comment: I try to install the 64 bit cd and it wont run in the drive is there any way i can wipe and reinstall through the terminal?

Comment: No, try using a live USB if you have one available.

Comment: If the 32bit disc ran in the machine, but the 64 bit didn't, then it sounds like your machine is 32bit only.

Comment: Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.

Comment: I'll make a usb from my samsung and try to run it on here. Is ubuntu prone to freezing / locking up on older pcs?

Comment: Depends on certain system specs, yes. Low ram can fail to mount the squashfs when installing. It really depends on the computer, though.

Comment: it looks like mine should support it @Zzzach...

Comment: let us know how the usb works